# Adding image to the SectionHeaderItem in Google Forms Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I've been using Google Apps Scripts to generate Google Forms and sent be email.
However, i've been trying to add a logo to the header section however there is no function or a possible way that I can find online of adding it.

I can add images using ImageItem(), however, this does not add to the header section and stays as a single item at the start of the form.

Is there anyway of adding images to the header section using google apps script or thats only possible using the customizable UI made for designing google forms?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What do you mean by "using the customizable UI made for designing google forms"?

Comment: If you make a normal Google Forms you can add an image to the header (https://www.bettercloud.com/monitor/the-academy/how-to-insert-a-logo-in-google-forms/). However, I can't seem to find the way to do it using google apps script. Even when using ImageItem() it doesn't stay in the header.

Comment: But this question is not about adding a image to the form header is about a "header section", if you mean the form header, please edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that for "header section" you mean the form header, the Forms Service doesn't include any class for the form header, so the only way to customize it is by using the Google Forms editor. By the other hand SectionHeaderItem, doesn't allow to insert images, only a title and a description.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms

Comment: Oh i did not know that... Thanks for the answer anyway !